# Create a WebPart that floats in text

Tags: 2010, web-part

I want to create a webPart that "floats" in text.
Basically I want to duplicate "Reusable Content".
Is there a way to have the webPart render as span and without chrome?

Comment: I accepted that this seems impossible using WebParts, I am looking for alternatives in http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/49091/how-would-i-rebuild-something-like-reusablecontent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 2010, you can insert web parts into content editor areas.  It will still be wrapped in normal web part tables.  No way around that.  You can turn the title bar (chrome) off in the Web Part settings.

Comment: So, there is NO WAY to have them being rendered inline in the text like "Reusble Content"?

Comment: Nope.  Web Parts unfortunately get rendered in the table containers that SharePoint uses.

Comment: You would need to do something outside of a web part (i.e. render something like your web part with JavaScript).