# How would I rebuild something like ReusableContent?

Tags: 2010, publishing-page, richhtmlfield

What I'd love to do:

- In a RichHtmlField of a publishing Page
- click "insert" in the ribbon, then "Foo"
- This let's me select from a list of "Foos"
- and inserts something that is not "contenteditable" but renders like a word or sentence.

My Idea:

- Add a button to the ribbon
- on click of that button add a span with `class="FOO" contenteditable="false" fragmentid="/Foo/0"` attributes to the RTE
- have javascript do some stuff to the span (find it using the class, update the content using the fragmentid)

Now here's the problem:

When I save the publishing page, the "custom attributes" contenteditable & fragmentid vanish from the source.

How can I make the RTE keep the custom attributes?

Or is there a better way to do this? (I.e. by creating a UserControl? But how would I insert this using the RTE?)

(Originally I wanted to use WebParts for this, but it seems I can not make them render "nicely", see [Create a WebPart that floats in text](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/47721/create-a-webpart-that-floats-in-text) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this question:
I was unable to retain these attributes.

I ended up using a button in RTE (insert Foo), which opens a selection of Foos and then adds a hyperlink with a specific class and an href url pointing to a list-item in the Foo's list.

The rest I did using JavaScript (update content on page-load, etc.)

All information I needed is now stored in a css class and the href. The contenteditable attribute is still missing (but would be nice to have...)